# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in sql command in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

getting error while initializing command text .unable add sql update query in sql command object

```
TextBox id = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtid");
TextBox Loginid = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtgvusername");
TextBox EmployeeId = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmployeeId");
TextBox Fullname = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFullname");
TextBox Password = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPassword");
TextBox ContactNo = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtContactNo");
TextBox MailId = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMailid");
TextBox Location = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLocation");
TextBox Roles = (TextBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRoles");

CheckBox chkLeads = (CheckBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkLeads");
CheckBox ChkSales = (CheckBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ChkSales");
CheckBox ChkReports = (CheckBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ChkReports");
CheckBox ChkPayments = (CheckBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ChkPayments");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Update tbl_AdminLogin set FullName='" + txtfullName.Text + "',Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "',ContactNo='" + txtContact.Text + "',Mailid='" + txtMailid.Text + "',Location='" + txtLocation.Text + "',Roles='" + Roles.Text + "',Leads='" + chkLeads.Text + "',Sales='" + ChkSales.Checked + "',Reports='" + ChkSales.Text + "',Payments='" + ChkPayments.Text + "',EmployeeId='" + id.Text + "' where id='" + id.Text + "'";//getting error here
```

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: Storing password as plain text is not good idea either.

Comment: `id` is null, you are not getting any textbox in `id`

Comment: no ..id is not null. im getting id value is  "18"

Comment: A wild guess due to lack of more information: NullReferenceException as one of the textboxes is null?

Comment: as a test, you could set a string variable to your update string and display it somewhere so you can see how it appears to the command object when it's submitted. This should show you what's missing. Also, Password is usually a reserved keyword in most database systems. You should consider wrapping that to denote it as a field and not a keyword or more preferably call it something other than Password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the `Control`s you're trying to find couldn't be found and `FindControl` returned `null`, and you were using the `Text` (or `Checked`) property of that `null` control. I don't know what are the names of your controls but I suspect that the problem is in that line:

```
    CheckBox chkLeads = (CheckBox)gvUserDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkLeads");
```

Because you the names of the rest of your `CheckBox`es got prefix "Chk" instead of "chk", try to fix it, and take a look on the first two comments on your question.